# Counting with Alexa

Tags: node.js, loops, count, alexa-skills-kit, translate

I'm trying to write an Alexa intent that will count up to a user given English number in Spanish. I can get Alexa to say the correct number in Spanish, but I'm having troubles trying to figure out how to get her to say more than one number.

Here is my code:

```
    const numbers = {
    'Zero':'Cero',
    'One': 'Uno',
    'Two' : 'Dos',
    'Three': 'Tres'    
    }

    const CountUpToIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'CountUpToIntent';
    },

    handle(handlerInput) {
        const numberToCountTo = 
handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.numberr.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name;
        const speechOutput = [];
        while (allTheNumbers !== 'Zero') {
            var allTheNumbers = numbers[numberToCountTo];    
            speechOutput.push(allTheNumbers--);
        }

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechOutput)
        .reprompt(speechOutput)
        .getResponse();
    }
    };
```

Can someone help me write the loop correctly, so Alexa says more than one number?

Thanks

Comment: have you tested it out?

Comment: Yes, neither suggestion worked. I'm still trying to work out the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing in wrong way and you are comparing `allTheNumbers` variable without even declaring it. One way you can solve this problem by taking number slot and when the user says some number then loop it with the given number. And check the given number for comparison which makes it easier.

```
const numbers = {
    '1':'Cero',
    '2':'Uno',
    '3':'Dos',
    '4':'Tres'    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [SSML](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask/test/amzn1.ask.skill.9848b0f8-faca-4cec-9ddb-662af739bfae/development/en_US/) you can easily speak in another language.

So you have to build your response with a simple for loop without your converting table, for example:

```
speech = "<speak><lang xml:lang='es-ES'>"

for(var i = 0; i < numberToCountTo; i++)
    speech += " " + i + " ";

speech += "</lang></speak>"
```